# Weighted nested set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-sets

Are there any gems or plugins that offer a nested set but with a weight also.

I want to be able to create a nested set and order each subset by its weight.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to just create a composite key index?

Answer (score 0):

Ancestry on git hub looks good

http://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

```
node.subtree.all(:order => :weight)
```

Has anyone done anything similar? I am interested to hear your solutions.